# Title on android acitivty

Tags: java, android

Всем привет!) Меня интересует возможность смены Title у Activity.

Comment: Такой вариант подойдет: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/254016/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-activity-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F ?

Comment: Да, огромное спасибо!)